How can I directly connect to SQL Server or Oracle using TMS WEB Core in Delphi?
As per the TMS WEB Core documentation, it seems like the primary way to access a database is through the corresponding REST API (XData) or Embarcadero's RAD Server. However, I find this approach cumbersome, especially when dealing with SQL Server or Oracle databases. Developing a REST service just to access my database seems like an unnecessary overhead, especially for small projects.
I have a few concerns:

⁠Time Constraints: It's a waste of time to create a custom REST service for every project just to enable database access.
⁠Cost and Dependencies: Many developers might not want to pay for RAD Server and XData solely for database connectivity. Additionally, I’d prefer to avoid additional dependencies on external services and technologies in my web applications.
⁠Business Application Needs: Most business applications require direct database connections, and the current REST-based approach doesn’t feel satisfactory.

Question: Is there any way to directly connect to SQL Server or Oracle databases using TMS WEB Core without relying on REST APIs?.

Please read: https://support.tmssoftware.com/t/direct-database-access/11309

There is not a way to connect Web Core without using a REST server.  You should learn how to create a REST server, it's not that difficult, and if done correctly offers better security.  TMS has a REST product if you don't want to use RAD Server.  RAD Server does have a learning curve, but once you understand it, it works very well.

Short Answer: You can't.
There is not currently a way to directly connect to any databases using Delphi or JavaScript in TMS WEB Core, because TMS WEB Core generates 100% client-side applications which means that none of the code runs on the server.
You can only connect directly to databases through server-side code. Therefore the best way to connect to a database on a client-side website is using a REST API Service.

The REST API Service also doesn't have to be made using TMS XData or RAD Server. You can make the REST API in any framework and/or language.
